# Magento2 <script type="text/x-magento-init"> after ajax

Tags: magento2, ajax, script

Lets say I want to get ajax response containing everything that is inside #maincontent selector on catalog/product/view/id/1 page.

The problem is that many JS (that works on product view page) doesn't work when I append ajax response html to my custom page (lets say my custom page is some category view page).

I noticed that scripts (from ajax response html) inside  doesnt work. like product gallery. How to make the scripts work? I noticed that after I add a product (using add to cart button from the response) the JS in  start to work - gallery becomes visible, related products show up, tabs working etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is very easy to solve.

Look in this line:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/mage/mage.js#L93

Here mage waiting when you insert html content with ajax: "text/x-magento-init".

Example:

you insert to

```
<div id="gallery"></div>
$('#gallery').html(content)
```

After call magento:

```
$('#gallery').trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Comment: this makes mage re-evaluate the whole page. what you want is mage to look only into the specified div. is it possible?

Comment: I have to use this with products load by infinite ajax scroll. I am using this https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-catalog-infinite-scroll but after scroll add to cart button is not working and reload page.

Comment: @Magecode, did you got the solution, I am also facing same issue

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any one have a solution?

Comment: `$('#gallery').trigger('contentUpdated');` not working

Comment: @jafarpinjar I am also facing the same issue .... Have you found out any solution for this?