# Execute JavaScript code after swatches are displayed in category view

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, category-view

I'm trying to trigger custom event whenever Magento displays the product swatches in category view.

It looks like Magento uses ajax to load these swatches, they are not displayed on page load, they "pop" after a few moments. I need to add some custom JavaScript code after these swatches are actually displayed. So I thought the best way will be to trigger custom event just after Magento finishes to render the swatches. But I'm not sure how to do this correctly in Magento 2.

[image]

What I want to do is to trigger a custom event `$(document).trigger('swatches-visible');` when a block of swatches is finally displayed on the page.

And then, an event handler will execute a function:

```
$(document).on('swatches-visible', function() { 
    doSomething(); 
});
```

That function `doSomething()` is already added via RequireJS in one of the template files:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery'], function(jQuery) {
        function doSomething()
        {
            // Here make some layout changes of the products list...
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you loading your script via RequireJS? I ask this as you can tell Require to only load a script when a certain element has been rendered with x-magento-ini. See this section of the dev docs for more info - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html#declarative-notation-using-the-script-typetextx-magento-init--tag-decltag

Comment: @Ben-Space48 I want to trigger custom event `$(document).trigger('swatches-visible')` when a block of swatches is finally displayed. And then, an event handler will execute a function: `$(document).on('swatches-visible', function(e) { doSomething(); });` That function `doSomething()` is already added via RequireJS in one of the template files. What you proposed sounds like a good solution but I'm not sure how to use it in my case. Isn't

Comment: Isn't `data-mage-init` executed only on page load? Note that the blocks of swatches for all products, e.g. `<div class="swatch-opt-1822">...</div>`, are displayed with a delay, not instantly on page load.

Comment: I know `data-mage-init` is, `x-magento-init` is different although I'm not sure if that is also only on page load (the dev docs don't mention). If it is page load then the only other method I can think of is to initialise the JS inside the swatch template. Require works in templates to so I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Although JS inside a template isn't the cleanest method :(

Comment: Or overwrite the swatch JS into your theme, name your JS as a dependency and then fire it from within the swatch JS?

Comment: @Ben-Space48 Can you write an answer with example of how to do it with `x-magento-init`? That might work. I'm not much into that `x-magento-init` thing yet, not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: Yeah sure, if I get time today I'll try it out and let you know. If it works I'll add an answer

Comment: I don't have time to look today sorry, but I have found some useful info. Magento has included a 'contentUpdated' handler(?) which looks like it watches for updates to the content. You could possibly be able to hook into this? See the following links for more info https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/mage/mage.js#L93 - https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=contentupdated - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92502/magento2-script-type-text-x-magento-init-after-ajax?rq=1

Comment: And http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127772/triggercontentupdated-just-for-an-element-of-the-page

Answer (score 12):

I used the event 'swatch.initialized' to fire a function after swatches are loaded in the product page:

```
$(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
  // do something
})
```

The event is triggered in `Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js`

```
$(this.element).trigger('swatch.initialized');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try With This one.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery','Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer'],function($,swatch){
                $(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
                   function doSomething()
                     {
                         // Here make some layout changes of the products list...
                     }
                });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Guillem Lorman's answer is good. A more general approach, which gives you more control, is to use mixins. This allows you to trigger your script before/after a certain function has completed. Like this:

*app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Namespace_ModuleName/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then go through the code of `swatch-renderer.js` to see before/after which function you'd like to trigger your code. E.g. to plug into `_RenderSwatchSelect` you could do the following:

*app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/viewfrontend/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js*

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function (
    $
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

            // Pay attention to parameters in the original function.
            _RenderSwatchSelect: function(config, chooseText) {
                // Trigger original function.
                this._super(config, chooseText);

                console.log('Yeah!');

                /**
                 * If you want to trigger your function before the original function, 
                 * you'd place this.super(config, chooseText) here.
                 */
            },
        });

        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly something that I was looking for. gives much more access than just initialise event. Thanks